# To visualise systematically look-behinds

Tags: regular-expression, perl, javascript

I am using Regexr to visualise my regexes now. 
I need look-behind but Javascript does not support it, example code [here](http://regexr.com/39r3c).
The project code base seems to be dependent Javascript (NodeJS) in [Github](https://github.com/gskinner/regexr/).
I am not sure if there is any way to avoid the problem.
I would like find another way to visualize lookbehinds.

Example data

```
http://www.masiPageBiologyNetwork.com#page=15
```

There are negative/positive lookbehind. 
I would like understand these terms better. 
Example positive lookbehind from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30932978/54964)

```
(?<=.)page(?=.)
```

**Is there way to go over this problem in visualising look-behind?**

Comment: turn  lookbehind into noncapturing group and get the string you want from group index 2.

Comment: How can you turn lookbehind here into *noncapturing group*? Can you give an example, please.

Comment: post an example string along with expected output.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I provided example data and one example lookbehind which I would like to visualize by some systemic way.

Comment: perl supports lookbehind where js won't. So you may use capturing groups `.(page).`

Comment: Directly in Perl? Any visualizing tool for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only sufficient tool for the task is still [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/) in Windows. 
No sufficient solution in Linux.